# how to generate client proxy class of a wcf service that will work in the .net 2.0

Tags: wcf-data-services, svcutil.exe, ssis-2005

I have to use a wcf service in the ssis script component which is developing in BIDS 2005. For this i have generated the proxy class of that service using `svcutil.exe`. After attaching the proxy class in the script component it has error of some class such as `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute` is not defined. Any suggestion how can i resolve this issue.. Or can wsdl is used to genrate proxy class of wcf service. so that it can be used in the .net 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after much struggling over it, i have resolved the issue. Now i have successfully created the proxy class of the wcf service and also it is now working in .net 2.0.

I have gone through the following steps:--

Note: this will work only if the wcf sercice(.svc) will be using BasicHttpBinding which is similar to webservice (.asmx)

**Step1:-**
run the following command on the visual studio command prompt.

```
svcutil.exe /target:metadata http://Your service address
```

It will create wsdl file with some other files in the path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC`

**Step2:-**
Now run the wsdl command

`wsdl.exe tempuri.org.wsdl tempuri.org.xsd schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd`

This will generate a v2.0 client proxy class that can be used to access the service.

Note: if some error occurs in the wsdl command, Use all the files name instead of using these three separated by space..